# Why do i keep getting UTC time zone even when Django settings is configured differently

Tags: python, django, timezone, utc

I'm not sure why the datetime response is always one hour behind (UTC)

Django settings configuration

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
TIME_ZONE = "Africa/Lagos"
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
DATE_FORMAT = "F j, Y"
SITE_ID = 1
```

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now()

response:
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 23, 13, 58, 6, 739601, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

You can see that the time zone info is UTC

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/p7qhvk/why_is_djangoutilstimezonenowtzinfo_returning_utc/)

> #### `now()`
>
> Returns a datetime that represents the current point in time. Exactly what’s returned depends on the value of `USE_TZ`:
>
> If `USE_TZ` is False, this will be a naive `datetime` (i.e. a datetime without an associated timezone) that represents the current time in the system’s local timezone.
>
> If `USE_TZ` is True, this will be an aware `datetime` representing the current time in UTC. Note that `now()` will always return times in UTC regardless of the value of `TIME_ZONE`; you can use `localtime()` to get the time in the current time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
1.download latest pytz file (pytz-2019.3.tar.gz) from
https://pypi.org/simple/pytz/

2.copy and extract it to site_packages directory on your project

3.in cmd go to the exracted folder and run "python setup.py install"

4.TIME_ZONE = 'Etc/GMT+3' or country name

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be done like this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
TIME_ZONE = "Africa/Lagos"
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False
```